# How can I read the exit code of a python script when testing in IDLE?

Tags: python, python-idle

I am testing a Python test script.  It is a collection of unittest test cases.  I would like to be able to return an overall pass or fail signal to the program that invokes this script.  In order to test it, I have been using IDLE, which works well.  How do I determine if the exit code from my script was correctly reported to IDLE?  I think it is working, as I can also launch it from a command line and then check the returned code.  I would like to be able to do this from IDLE as well.

Comment: Return codes imply subprocesses.  However in this case you are probably looking for a test runner: probably pytest.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've not really got the point. What do you mean by `signal`? I'm thinking of IDLE as just a tool that prepares the environment for the script to be run, and runs it. How should IDLE handle (receive + do something with) the *signal*?

Comment: @Buzz I am using the English word signal, not a technical term.  I just want to be able to test my tests to see what error code they are returning.  When IDLE launches something to run my script it can, once the script exits, receive the error code returned.  I want to know how to see that returned code.